# How to get alert when a user is redirected to the fail over machine?

Tags: c#

I have an application which is hosted on two machines(one is fail over) with same name.Recently i have found that some user are redirected to my fail over even main machine is working fine (not down). I just want to identify through an email or alert when user goes to the fail over. Any idea is much appreciated.

Comment: What technologies are you using to direct the web traffic?

Comment: How is this connected to C#? Are you sure that this is a question about programming?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to differentiate between two different installations of the same application, my first instinct would add a web.config key to do just this.

E.g.:

```
<add key="failoverServer" value="true">
```

Based on that key, you can add a check in your application that checks this key and acts accordingly.
If no one ever reaches the failover server, it will never process a request and thus not alert you unless someone managed to get onto the server (probably because the main server is down).

But I'm not aware if there are other options more suited to this approach (e.g. I can imagine a failover system has a way of reporting server downtime). It just seems the simplest solution to implement in the application itself.